# asp.net mvc 2 UIHint with multiple defonitions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

im using data annotation with buddy classes for error etc
however i have a field for photo on the view it should be an image
but on the edit and add it should be a file upload ???

but UIHint will only let me have one, so how do you have multiple UI
for one type in your class?

thanks

Comment: UIHint is the ability to define say a dropdown box for category instead of a textbox (textbox would be the default for editorFor and Displayfor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only need to specify one UIHint. Within the Views\ControllerName folder or Views\Shared you have two additional sub folders DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates. So when you call:

```
<%=Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name) %>
```

This will look in your DisplayTemplates folder for a control with the UIHint name which in your case will be an images, and when you call:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name) %>
```

This will look in your EditorTemplates folder for a control with the UIHint name which will be a file uploader.

Here's an basic editor example that should help you: [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804032742/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx).